# simple html dom parsing first child into an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, simple-html-dom

Consider an html code as follow

```
<html>
<div class="allItems">
   <div class="Item" id="12345">
      <div class="ItemName">Tom</div>
      <div class="ItemAge">34</div>
      <div class="ItemGender">male</div>
   </div>
   <div class="Item" id="17892">
      <div class="ItemName">Dick</div>
      <div class="ItemAge">23</div>
      <div class="ItemGender">male</div>
   </div>
   <div class="Item" id="98776">
      <div class="ItemName">Harry</div>
      <div class="ItemAge">65</div>
      <div class="ItemGender">male</div>
   </div>
</div>
</html>
```

I am trying to parse this html document as follow:

```
<?php

include_once("/simple_html_dom.php");

<--a bunch of code that works until here -->

$html = str_get_html($str); //this pulls the html code fine

//this is where my array constructions does not work
foreach ($html->find('div.allItems > *') as $article) {
   $item['name'] = $html->find('div.ItemName', 0)->plaintext;
   $item['age'] = $html->find('div.ItemAge',0)->plaintext;
   $item['gender'] = $html->('div.ItemGender', 0)->plaintext;
   $articles[] = $item;
}

print_r($articles);

?>
```

## What I would expect to get:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Tom [Age] => 34 [Gender] => male ) 
[1] => Array ( [name] => Dick [Age] => 23 [Gender] => male ) 
[2] => Array ( [name] => Harry [Age] => 65 [Gender] => male )
```

## Instead this is What I get

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Tom [Age] => 34 [Gender] => male ) 
[1] => Array ( [name] => Tom [Age] => 34 [Gender] => male ) 
[2] => Array ( [name] => Tom [Age] => 34 [Gender] => male )
```

## My Question therefore:

How can I get the desired array?

Comment: You wanted `$article->find` instead of `$html->find`. See why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on right track, the only think is you need to set index of div as second parameter of `find` function. have a look on below solution:

```
include_once("simple_html_dom.php");
$str = '<html>
<div class="allItems">
   <div class="Item" id="12345">
      <div class="ItemName">Tom</div>
      <div class="ItemAge">34</div>
      <div class="ItemGender">male</div>
   </div>
   <div class="Item" id="17892">
      <div class="ItemName">Dick</div>
      <div class="ItemAge">23</div>
      <div class="ItemGender">male</div>
   </div>
   <div class="Item" id="98776">
      <div class="ItemName">Harry</div>
      <div class="ItemAge">65</div>
      <div class="ItemGender">male</div>
   </div>
</div>
</html>';

$html = str_get_html($str); //this pulls the html code fine

//this is where my array constructions does not work
$i = 0;
foreach ($html->find('div.allItems > *') as $article) {
    $item['name'] = $html->find('div.ItemName', $i)->plaintext;
    $item['age'] = $html->find('div.ItemAge',$i)->plaintext;
    $item['gender'] = $html->find('div.ItemGender', $i)->plaintext;
    $articles[] = $item;
    $i++;
}

print_r($articles);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Tom
            [age] => 34
            [gender] => male
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Dick
            [age] => 23
            [gender] => male
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Harry
            [age] => 65
            [gender] => male
        )

)
```

Comment: I dont want to be critic, but this is awful way to approach numeric $i needs with foreach, which is for arrays. You could have just done `for ($i = 1; $i <= count($html->find('div.allItems > *')); $i++) { // ...`